# How to quick find a jar package that matches my current jdk version

Tags: java, maven, jar

I used IDEA for java maven developing. My jdk version is too low too support some jar packages, I hope I can downgrade the packages for quick demo.

For example, my current jdk version is 15, but the package below needs jdk 17, and my current idea do not support jdk 17, so I want to downgrade spring-cloud-config-server to match jdk 15, how do I make it?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

1. I guess there maybe a website keeps jar info history or something that can be a good solution. But I didn't find that.
2. There are a lot of answer said to check MANIFEST.MF to find the jdk version, but I think those are not suit for my purpose.

Comment: By the way… Are you aware that Java 15 is past end-of-life, and not receiving any bug fixes nor any security patches? You should be using either a Long-Term Support (LTS) version (8, 11, 17) or the current version (20, soon to be 21). Tip: [*SDKMAN!*](https://sdkman.io/) makes installing and removing JDKs quite simple and easy.

Comment: Yes, I agreed with you for long-term support.

Answer (score 1):

## Maven ignorant of minimum-Java-version requirements

> I want to downgrade spring-cloud-config-server to match jdk 15

Maven cannot do that for you, not automatically. Maven is completely ignorant of any particular dependency’s requirement regarding a version of Java.

Minimum-Java-version checking *would* be a neat feature. But that is currently not currently in the scope of Maven.

You will need to do the research to discover what version of your needed library/framework will work with your chosen version of Java.

Once you have learned the necessary version, you *can* specify that version number in your Maven POM. To specify a version, use the `<version>` element.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That should be a little unfriendly I guess. haha.  If there is a jar-version  java-version mapping  website. My case is easy.

Comment: @nickhuang it is cumbersome but that’s how maven works. Java version is not something maven cares about.   Find the version you need and specify it.